# Python return response as a string or undefined

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, reddit, praw

Adapted below from [this found on GitHub](https://github.com/MrEdinLaw/TwitterToReddit-Bot/blob/master/init.py).

Trying to adapt the code meant for posting a recent tweet as a new post to a Subreddit to instead post the contents of the recent tweet as a comment.

This work if I use the code from GitHub to make a post. If I adapt for a comment I end up with a string response that says "tweet" like this `REPLY_TEMPLATE = 'tweet'` , instead of displaying the tweet that was pulled in.

```
def get_last_tweet(self):
    tweet = self.user_timeline(user_id="XXXXXXXX", count=1, tweet_mode="extended")[0]
    print('tweet')
    return tweet

REPLY_TEMPLATE = tweet

def process_submission(submission):
    # Ignore titles for any thread with the same title that is not pinned
    if not submission.stickied:
        return

    normalized_title = submission.title.lower()
    for active_daily in POST:
        if active_daily in normalized_title:
            url_title = quote_plus(submission.title)
            reply_text = REPLY_TEMPLATE.format(url_title)
            print(f"Replying to: {submission.title}")
            submission.reply(body=reply_text)
```

I tried this below as well, but I get a `NameError: name 'tweet' is not defined` error

```
def get_last_tweet(self):
    global tweet
    tweet = self.user_timeline(user_id="XXXXXXXX", count=1, tweet_mode="extended")[0]
print('tweet')


REPLY_TEMPLATE = tweet
```

Comment: `tweet` *isn't* defined outside `get_last_tweet`. You need to call `get_last_tweet` first: `REPLY_TEMPLATE = some_object.get_last_tweet()`.

Comment: It's true. `tweet` is not defined. If every name you use in every function you define was suddenly available everywhere, your code would be very confusing, unmanageable even.